# What are the absorption and emission spectra of $\rm H^+$ ion (a proton)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, photon-emission, ions

Does $\rm H^+$  even produce emission spectrum without an electron?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does H+ even produce emission spectrum without an electron?

Without any electrons around, there would be no electronic emission spectra. E.g., the usual photon-based absorption and emission would not occur. E.g., we would not see the usual Balmer series, Lyman series, etc., since there can be no electronic spectra without electrons.

Comment: Does it mean it doesn't have electronic absorption spectrum as well?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The usual absorption "lines" (or "edges" in a solid) occur because electrons in bound states are excited to electronic continuum states. Without any electrons there would be none of the usual x-ray absorption lines either.

Comment: ENDF finds no gamma levels for a proton. A more complex nucleus, yes, but a single proton?

Comment: @JonCuster I wasn't aware... I'm a solid state guy, not a nuclear guy. I'll update.

Comment: Proton excited states can decay by photon emission. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/528742/can-neutrons-and-protons-have-excited-states

Comment: @JohnDoty Good to know. I'll leave that fact in the comments and will not update the answer, since it seems to me like OP is mainly interested in x-ray spectra.

Comment: I wouldn't call any electronic emission from H "x-rays", although Lyman alpha is, of course, analogous to the K alpha x-rays of higher Z stuff.

Comment: The hydrogen emissions and absorption spectra are going to have a characteristics scale of a few eV to tens of eVs... I'd still call it x-rays, even though I guess those are pretty "soft" x-rays, and so my terminology might not be strictly correct.... Anyways, it's higher energy than visible.

Comment: I changed the word "x-ray" to "photon" in the answer.